# R Shiny increase header height remove dot next to navigation icon

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

So when I increase the height of the main header in a Shinydashboard app all of a sudden a dot appears...why? And how can I remove it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    title = "Test",
    header = dashboardHeader(
# increase header height
      tags$li(
        class = "dropdown",
        tags$style(".main-header {min-height: 75px}")
      ),
      title = a(target="_blank", href = 'https://www.google.com',
                img(src = 'https://img.freepik.com/free-icon/search_318-265146.jpg', title = "Test", height = "75px"))
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody()
  )

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solved it:

```
tagList(
        tags$style(".main-header {min-height: 75px}")
      )
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Hi Jeremey...for me its also all trial-and-error cause Im not a experienced in HTML...thats why I asked the question here...