# Black dot header notification using uiOutput and renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, taglist

When I want to use a Left sided notification using renderUI..somehow a black dot is appearing, which isnt the if you just place the leftUI in the UI section. Why?

I had the same issue in the UI when I used tags$li though I solved it using tagList, see: [R Shiny increase header height remove dot next to navigation icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651702/r-shiny-increase-header-height-remove-dot-next-to-navigation-icon)

and

[R shiny image and removing black dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76456303/r-shiny-image-and-removing-black-dot)

but puting it in renderUI it reappears

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(
    uiOutput("left_ui")
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = bs4DashBody(
    uiOutput("moreControls")
  ),
  controlbar = uiOutput("controlbarmen")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$left_ui = renderUI({
    
    leftUi = tagList(
      dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", badgeStatus = "danger",
                   notificationItem(
                     text = "Test",
                     icon("circle-exclamation"),
                     status = "danger")
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$moreControls <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      sliderInput("n", "N", 1, 1000, 500),
      textInput("label", "Label")
    )
  })
  
  output$controlbarmen = renderUI({
    NULL
      )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
  header = dashboardHeader(
    leftUi = uiOutput("left_ui")
  )
```

and it disappears.

The `leftUi` in your `renderUI` is useless.

Comment: Wauw that east thx!!!

Comment: Hi I have an update with a similar kinda issue...I updated the question: when I want to renderUI the controlbar with NULL is gives an Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag' error..how come?